# Javascript Function is calling on submit when done

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a button that removes a photo from an object that holds multiple photos:

```
<button class="btn" onClick={()=> this.removePhoto(index)}>remove</button>
```

For some reason after the removePhoto function runs it continues to the onsubmit function. The only thing I can think that could be causing this is the bindings but I am still a fairly new to react so I am not sure how to fix this.

```
export default class Edit extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        id: '',
        title: '',
        description: '',
        photos: [], 
        categories: [],
        selectedFile: '',
        selectedFiles: '',
        photo: '',
        tags: [],
        tagName: '',
    };  
    this.removePhoto = this.removePhoto.bind(this);
   }
   
 
  onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault(); 
    const photoCatUpdate = this.state.photos.map((obj, index) => {  
      obj.tag = this.state.tagName
      return obj
    });

    const photos = JSON.stringify(photoCatUpdate)
    let body = {
        title: this.state.title,
        description : this.state.description,
        photos: photos,
        tags: this.state.tagName
    }
    let id = this.state.id

    fetch('/api/categories/' + id, {
      method: 'put',
      body: JSON.stringify(body),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    })
    .then(res => {
      if (res.status === 200) {
          console.log("WORKED!!")
          this.props.closeModal()
          this.props.getCategory()
       
      } else {
        const error = new Error(res.error);
        throw error;
      }
    })
  }

        addPhoto = () => {
          const photosNew = this.state.photos
          const photo = this.state.photo
          photosNew.push({
            photo: photo,
            title: '',
            thumbnail: false,
            image1: false,
            image2: false,
            tag: '',
          });
          this.setState({photos: photosNew});
          this.setState({photo: '', selectedFile: '', selectedFiles: ''})
          document.getElementById("myFile").value = "";
        }
         
  removePhoto = (i) => {
    debugger
    const photos = this.state.photos
    const objIndex = photos.filter((obj, index) => {
      if(index != i){
        return obj
      }
    });

    console.log("objIndex", objIndex)

    this.setState({photos: objIndex})
    
  }
   
  updatePhotoObj = (event) => {
    const { value, id } = event.target;
    console.log("value", value)
    console.log("event.target", event.target)
    
    const objIndex = this.state.photos.map((obj, index) => {
      if(index == id){
        obj.title = value
      }
      return obj
    });

    this.setState({photos: objIndex})

  }
  handleInputChangeRadio = (event) => {
    const { name, id} = event.target;
    console.log("GET HERE!", name)
    console.log("GET HERE!", id)
    const objIndex = this.state.photos.map((obj, index) => {
      if(index == id){
        obj.thumbnail = true
      }else{
        obj.thumbnail = false
      }
      return obj
    });

    this.setState({photos: objIndex})
  }
  handleInputChangeOne = (event) => {
    const { name, id} = event.target;
    console.log("GET HERE!", name)
    console.log("GET HERE!", id)
    const objIndex = this.state.photos.map((obj, index) => {
      if(index == id){
        obj.image1 = true
      }else{
        obj.image1 = false
      }
      return obj
    });

    this.setState({photos: objIndex})
  }
  handleInputChangeTwo = (event) => {
    const { name, id} = event.target;
    console.log("GET HERE!", name)
    console.log("GET HERE!", id)
    const objIndex = this.state.photos.map((obj, index) => {
      if(index == id){
        obj.image2 = true
      }else{
        obj.image2 = false
      }
      return obj
    });

    this.setState({photos: objIndex})
  }
   
  render() {
    const table = {
      width: '100%',
      paddingTop: '20px'
     }
   
    return (
      <> 
     

     <div class="col-md-12">  
    <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Title</label>
     <input
           class="form-control" 
           type="text"
          name="title"
          placeholder="Enter title"
          value={this.state.title}
          onChange={this.handleInputChange}
        />
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-group">
    <label>Description</label>
     <textarea
           class="form-control" 
           type="text"
           rows="10" 
          name="description"
          placeholder="Enter title"
          value={this.state.description}
          onChange={this.handleInputChange}
        />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputTag">Tag</label>
        <select id="inputTag" class="form-control"
                        value={this.state.tagName}
                        name="tagName"
                        onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                        >
                           <option  value="" disabled selected>Please Choose...</option>
                        {this.state.tags.map(s =>  
                            <option selected>{s.name}</option>
                        )}
                        </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
        <label>New Photo</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
       <input type="file" id="myFile" onChange={this.singleFileChangedHandler}/>   
          <button className="btn btn-secondary" onClick={this.singleFileUploadHandler}>Add Photo</button>
          </div>
      
        <div class="form-row">
        {this.state.photos.length > 0 ?
          <div style={table}>
         
          <div class="table-responsive-sm">
                        <table class="table table-hover">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col">photos</th>
                                    <th scope="col"></th>
                  <th scope="col"></th>
                  <th scope="col"></th>
                  <th scope="col"></th>
                                
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            
                {this.state.photos.map((x, index) => {
                return (
                  <>
                  <tr>
                        <td > <img src={x.photo} alt=""/></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td> 
                          <button class="btn" onClick={()=> this.removePhoto(index)}>remove</button>
                          <div class="form-check">
                            <input 
                            class="form-check-input" 
                            type="radio" name="thumb" id={index} 
                            name="thumb"
                            checked={x.thumbnail}
                            onChange={this.handleInputChangeRadio}
                            />
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="thumb">
                              Thumbnail
                            </label>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-check">
                            <input 
                            class="form-check-input" 
                            type="radio" name="one" id={index} 
                            name="one"
                            checked={x.image1}
                            onChange={this.handleInputChangeOne}
                            />
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="one">
                              Image 1
                            </label>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-check">
                            <input 
                            class="form-check-input" 
                            type="radio" name="two" id={index} 
                            name="two"
                            checked={x.image2}
                            onChange={this.handleInputChangeTwo}
                            />
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="two">
                              Image 2
                            </label>
                          </div>
                        </td>
                       
                      </tr>
                       <tr>
                      <input
                   class="form-control" 
                   type="text"
                   value={x.title}
                   id={index}
                   onChange={this.updatePhotoObj}
                 />
                 </tr>
              </>
                );
                
              })}
                
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
          </div>
        :
        null
     
      
      }
      
       </div>
     
        <div class="modal-footer"> 
       <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" onClick={this.handleClose}>Close</button>
       </div>
      </form> 
      </div>
    
      </>
      );
    
    }
  }
```

Comment: Not the answer, but I don't think you need `this.removePhoto = this.removePhoto.bind(this);` in your constructor because the removePhoto function is an arrow func

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most importantly you have to add type to the button

```
 <button type="button" class="btn" onClick={()=> this.removePhoto(index)}>remove</button>
```

Buttons Without type inside form is by default `type="submit"` so when you click on it, it will submit the form

I think there is better way to filter the array

```
const filterdPhotos = photos.filter((obj, index) => {
    return index != i;
});

this.setState({photos: filterdPhotos})
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason it triggers your `onSubmit` is because you have a `button` inside a `form` with no specified type.

I believe if you simply declare `type="button"` to prevent the browser from *assuming* it's a submit button you should be good to go.

So you would want:

```
<button class="btn" type="button" onClick={()=> this.removePhoto(index)}>remove</button>
```